# Discover errors in Invalid Record factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I have a user factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "email@x.com"
    password "123456789"
  end
end
```

I am trying to create a spec for the user:

```
describe User do
  it "should create a user with password" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, password: "secret")
    user.password.should == "secret"
  end   
end
```

When I run the test, I get this message:

```
  1) User should create a user with password
     Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, password: "secret")
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       is invalid
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

The problem is: how to discover what are the fields in the model that are invalid? In other words, how to print the error messages inside the model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always temporarily change your test to:

```
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, password: "secret")
```

and then check `user.valid?` and `user.errors`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the `build` method gives you the same `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Record invalid`. In that case you might want to look for any associated records that your factory creates, maybe the validation problem comes from those instead.

Comment: If I haven't misunderstood what you were saying, then it's impossible to get the error when building a record, as build shouldn't trigger .save! on a record. If your record triggers .save! on making a new record, then you might be doing something really wrong.